# Spark Streaming UI - Input Rows vs Input Rate

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

My Spark application (structured streaming) displays a number of Input Rows which is much higher than the number of records I'm sending to the application (in my case the input rows in the UI is always 21 times the number of actual records).

I can't find a clear explanation of what exactly the "Input Rows" means. I read somewhere that this was related to the number of actions performed on the dataset but the math doesn't add up.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Number of input rows are nothing but the total number of rows in a batch. For example if next batch trigger for every 20 seconds and input rate is 10, then your input rows will be 200.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/web-ui.html#structured-streaming-tab